# Magento update errors

Tags: magento-1.9, error, upgrade, search

I recently updated my shop from Magento 1.6.1 to 1.9.2.3. When I look at the webshop, the overall of it looks fine. But when I use the search functionality for example, I receive the following fatal error.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:718:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'price_index.min_price' in 'field list', query was: SELECT FLOOR(((price_index.min_price +(price_index.min_price*CASE price_index.tax_class_id WHEN 5 THEN       0.2100 WHEN 6 THEN       0.0600  ELSE 0 END)) * 1) / 10) + 1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_result` AS `search_result` ON search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id='2672'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2' WHERE (price_index.min_price > 0) GROUP BY `range`";i:1;s:5786:"#0 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT FLOOR(((...', Array)
#4 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT FLOOR(((...', Array)
#5 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(811): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Resource/Filter/Price.php(85): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchPairs(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(158): Mana_Filters_Resource_Filter_Price->getCount(Object(Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Price), 10)
#8 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(115): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getRangeItemCounts(10)
#9 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Filter/Price.php(137): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getPriceRange()
#10 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Filter/Price.php(100): Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Price->_getItemsData()
#11 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(120): Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Price->_initItems()
#12 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(109): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItems()
#13 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#14 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/design/frontend/xxxx/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml(48): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#15 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/users/tet...')
#16 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/xxx...')
#17 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#21 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#23 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/design/frontend/xxxx/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#24 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/users/tet...')
#25 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/xxx...')
#26 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#30 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php(80): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#31 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController->indexAction()
#32 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#33 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 /home/users/tetewftp/xxxx/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}";s:3:"url";s:42:"/catalogsearch/result/?q=Alabastine+voegen";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you try disabling the Mana_Filters module and see if the error is still happening ?

Comment: When I disable this module, the whole site goes down

Comment: Check under var/log and var/report if you're getting an error in the files under those directories

Comment: The errors that I posted above are the errors in the var/report file

Comment: I meant the error you're getting when disabling the Mana_Filters module

Comment: Did you confirm that you Mana filters module is compatible with this new version or they may have a new version of their module.

Comment: Does the site work when you turn off the module and switch the site theme into the default theme?

Answer (score -1):

their is an error in your Query.
Please use same alias in all Query.
Try below Query in your Database or phpmyadmin and do appropriate like that.

```
SELECT FLOOR(((e.min_price +(e.min_price*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 5 THEN 0.2100 WHEN 6 THEN 0.0600 ELSE 0 END)) * 1) / 10) + 1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_result` AS `search_result` ON search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id='2672' INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2' WHERE (e.min_price > 0) GROUP BY `range`
```